# How to vertically position some text at the centre of a circle div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a circle shaped div with some text directly in the middle. I can get it horizontally in the middle, easily but I am having loads of trouble getting it in the vertical center, I've tried doing vertical-align, padding, display etc but it'll always stay right at the top.

Here's the offending HTML:

```
<div class="widget">
    <p id='case'>{27 cases}</p>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS for that div:

```
.widget {
    background-color: #ff1122;
    color: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I'm trying to get the text precisely in the middle of the circle vertically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `line-height` property. Make the `line-height` equal to the height of the circle, in this case `150px`.

```
line-height:150px;
```

```css
.widget {
    background-color: #ff1122;
    color: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
    <p id='case'>{27 cases}</p>
</div>
```

If you are open to using flex-box you can also do this instead. This will work for multiple lines.

```css
.widget {
    background-color: #ff1122;
    color: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
  <p id='case'>This is multiple line text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This will create issues if the text is multiple lines. I believe using `display: table-cell` would be a more use-case solution personally, but to each their own.

Comment: I updated my answer to include two ways, one for single line and the other for multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```css
.widget {
    background-color: #f12;
    color: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.widget * {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.widget::before {
  content: "";
  display:inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
    <p id='case'>{27 cases}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the circle `display: table;` and the inside `p` have `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;`.

```css
.widget {
    background-color: #ff1122;
    color: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: table;
}

.widget p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
    <p id='case'>{27 cases}</p>
</div>
```